# LCM of Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

I know for integers we have

$$\operatorname{lcm}(n,m) = \frac{nm}{\gcd(n,m)}$$

Does this hold for polynomials? i.e. $\operatorname{lcm}(f(x),g(x)) = \dfrac{f(x)g(x)}{\gcd(f(x),g(x))}$

Comment: Do you mean lcm instead of lcd?

Comment: Polynomials over what type of coefficient ring?

Comment: Polynomials over a field $F_3$, that's all the information I have. And yes, I meant lcm, thanks Mathi!

Comment: \gcd is a standard operator name; you don't need to write \operatorname{gcd}. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does hold but with a little difference! $\operatorname{L.C.M.}=\frac{P(x)\cdot Q(x)}{\operatorname{G.C.D.}(P(X),Q(X))\cdot \operatorname{DOM}(Q)\cdot\operatorname{DOM}(P)}$! $\operatorname{DOM}(P)$ is the leading coefficient! If $P(x)=1+x+3x^3$ hence $\operatorname{DOM}\{P\}=3$.

Comment: Hmm. So if I'm looking for the lcm of f(x) = $x^3-x^2-1$ and g(x) = $x^2-x+1$, I can just take f(x)g(x)/ gcd(f(x),g(x))?

Comment: True! Dom(p) and Dom(q) both equal 1